# Erlang Facebook Example

Tags: erlang, facebook, mochiweb

Does anyone know of an example facebook app (or facebook connect app) done in Erlang? I'm looking for something that includes the whole process. Specifically I don't seem to find anything on user authentication.

I've checked out [erlang_facebook](http://github.com/ngerakines/erlang_facebook), erlang2facebook and erlyface but none of them seem to offer a simple and comprehensive example accessible to me as a beginner .
I'd be happy for just a bit of code to plough through though, preferably using mochiweb as backend.

Answer (score 2):

I've played around writing a FB app in Erlang and looked at the projects you mentioned as well. I found it easier to just use FB's [graph API](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/) directly for authentication, etc. I used Nitrogen/Mochiweb for the web server and made graph requests with httpc:request.

Answer (score 1):

Zotonic (Erlang CMS/Framework) provides Facebook integration, including authentication.

http://zotonic.com/mod-facebook

Answer (score 0):

A few years on and I still find Jeremy Raymond's method satisfying. In particular, wrapping their ever-changing url-as-an-API scheme inside your own API seems to be the most painless. httpc is useful, and so is cowboy if you are familiar with that.

Whatever you choose, you should absolutely not be designing *your* ideas around *their* API. Convert their ideas into your project's semantics by wrapping their API. After all, the web isn't the whole internet and you never know when FB might stop being the cool place to waste your life. There is no telling if your application/library/codebase-you-use-on-something-else will outlive theirs.